# Upgrading firefox on Red Hat

Tags: firefox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to upgrade my version of firefox at work, the installed OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.4 (Tikanga) over which we have no control. Also note that we do not have access to our /usr/bin directories.

I've downloaded the newest version of Firefox, and unzipped to my home directory. When I run firefox from this directory, I get (I have turned debugging on in the firefox shell script):

```
+ moz_libdir=/usr/local/lib/firefox-3.6.12
+ found=0
+ progname=./firefox
++ dirname ./firefox
+ curdir=.
++ basename ./firefox
+ progbase=firefox
+ run_moz=./run-mozilla.sh
+ test -x ./run-mozilla.sh
+ dist_bin=.
+ echo .
.
+ found=1
+ '[' 1 = 0 ']'
+ script_args=
+ debugging=1
+ MOZILLA_BIN=firefox-bin
+ '[' linux = beos ']'
+ pass_arg_count=0
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
+ echo ./run-mozilla.sh ./firefox-bin
./run-mozilla.sh ./firefox-bin
+ ./run-mozilla.sh ./firefox-bin
+ exitcode=0
+ exit 0
```

ie: it looks to be executing the firefox binary and run-mozilla.sh script in the current directory (the new version of firefox). However, when firefox starts, it says it is version 3.01 (I have downloaded 3.6). I believe this is because the default install of firefox on the machine is 3.01 - the file /usr/bin/firefox (ie: the old version) contains:

moz_libdir=/usr/local/lib/firefox-3.0.1

(interestingly this directory does not exist)

I think it's somehow picking up this old version, although the trace from when debug is turned on looks like it's executing the new binary version.

Does anyone know how to change this behaviour so that the new version of firefox runs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either shut down the old version of Firefox completely, or pass `-no-remote` to the script for the new version.